# paginacion en tabla dinamica

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

primero que todo gracias por su colaboracion.
Estoy creando una tabla donde se agregan filas al hacer click en un boton y el problema que tengo es que necesito agregar una paginación por ejemplo de cada 10 filas.
Si alguien me podria orientar se lo agradeceria mucho, este es mi ejemplo:

[tabla ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/f1ehoaLk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay muchas formas de hacer, pero existe un plugin llamado datatables que lo hace muy bien y tiene buscador y todo. La dependencia que usa es Jquery, y tambien puedes integrarlo con bootstrap.

https://datatables.net/

Ahí esta toda la documentación.

Espero sea de ayuda Salu2

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero en realidad creo que ese plugin en el momento no es lo que requiero pues la información se va agregando fila por fila

Comment: tendrias que hacer un script, que cada vez que agregues una fila, este mida la cantidad de filas y realice la paginación

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo es que en realidad no se como hacer eso, gracias

Comment: Estás trabajando con Ajax?

Comment: si, pero para la carga inicialmente esta vacía

Comment: Acá está una pregunta similar para paginar con javascript [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434813/simple-pagination-in-javascript] solo sigue el mismo ejemplo, y cada vez que sea insertado un registro, verifica la cantidad que tienes, y asi vas paginando, cualquier duda, solo escribe

Comment: lo revisare, gracias